# Having trouble ending up with negative or no discount

Tags: python-3.x

https://gist.github.com/Socialery/bf0f39375150dcfefd3b

For example if I enter 0, -47, 8 the total comes out correct but it gives me a discount of 0 and final total of 0.

Comment: Instead of giving a link, you can actually copy-paste your question fine here. In particular because it's not too large. Were it too large, you should remove all unnecessary details until only the actual problem remains, making it much clearer and easier to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're not recalculating "total" if you get invalid input.  With the input you mentioned "total" will be set to zero initially and will never be set again.  You use `num * Price` in the print statement.